# div with not fix width in the center of page - CSS

Tags: css

I have a div that will show a picture in a bigger size.

So I want this div to be in the center of the screen. but margin 0 auto is not working...

CSS:

```
.form_postloader{
 max-width: 1100px;
 min-height: 400px;
 background: #ffffff;
 color: #000;
 position:absolute; 
 margin:0 auto;
 display:block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/t5t031zj/

thank you!

Comment: `position:absolute` can't be used with that technique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's not working because it's absolute positioned. You could remove the position absolute, or, if you need it you can do it like so:

```
position:absolute;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%);
```

no need to set width, completely responsive!

http://jsfiddle.net/t5t031zj/2/

Answer (score 1):

Due to `position:absolute` you need to use `left` and `right` to do this.

```
left:0;
right:0;
width: 400px;
```

Applying these to your box will center it, the issue is that you need to set a width.

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/t5t031zj/3/